# Accessing name and id of object - Javascript

Tags: javascript

So i have this following object in Javascript, and I am interested in only `id: '410467873518256138', name: 'element1'`

How can i extract this information from the object?
I tried storing it in object and doing `object.id` or `object.name` but it prints nothing.

```
'410467873518256138' => Emoji {
  guild:
   Guild {
     members: [Object],
     channels: [Object],
     roles: [Object],
     presences: [Object],
     available: true,
     id: '410467289767346186',
     name: 'emoji_set4',
     icon: null,
     splash: null,
     region: 'singapore',
     memberCount: 2,
     large: false,
     features: [],
     applicationID: null,
     afkTimeout: 300,
     afkChannelID: null,
     systemChannelID: '410467289767346188',
     embedEnabled: undefined,
     verificationLevel: 0,
     explicitContentFilter: 0,
     joinedTimestamp: 1517933748730,
     ownerID: '352458321456005123',
     _rawVoiceStates: Collection {},
     emojis: [Object] },
  id: '410467873518256138',
  name: 'element1',
  requiresColons: true,
  managed: false,
  animated: false,
  _roles: [] },
```

Also kindly explain what this syntax is `'410467873518256138' => Emoji {`, cause generally we write `variable = {}` to define an object.

Comment: How are you printing out the above/

Comment: What you have quoted is not JavaScript source code. I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Whatever it is you should try object.guild.id and object.guild.name as that's the structure I can see from what you have in your post.

Comment: @GSazheniuk looks more like object.Emoji.guild.Guild.id

Comment: @Darkrum nope, Emoji and Guild are names of the classes

Comment: In this way, you can get the key, `Object.keys(obj)`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @Yumiko On doing object.keys, I get the 'id' part before => Emoji, how do I access the name and ID then